# Timestamp and date inconsistent return

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm confused about something basic I thought I understood.

Here's my code:

```
echo strtotime('2019-04-02 10:12:13');
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1554217933');
```

I expect to see this output:

```
1554217933
2019-04-02 10:12:13
```

and do on my local env. When I test remotely, I see this:

```
1554199933
2019-04-02 15:12:13
```

How does that work? I thought a timestamp was universal Even if the timezones on the different environments are set differently, the value of `strtotime`for a static date should output the same timestamp, shouldn't it?

Comment: TL;DR: your server is in a different *timezone*! [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

Comment: @u_mulder the number of seconds from 01.01.1970 is the same regardless of what timezone you start in. I'm obviously missing something in the logic here.

Comment: What timezone is `2019-04-02 10:12:13` in? PHP needs to know that to give you an absolute timestamp. Since that string doesn’t include any timezone information, PHP is using the (implicitly) set default timezone.